# Retrieve and pass values from JSON onject array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax

I'm trying to update a program that currently uses an internal array of objects

```
var questions = [
    {
     question: "What is 2*5?",
     choices: [2, 5, 10, 15, 20],
     correctAnswer: 2
    }
];
```

And have it use an external JSON file that has an array of objects

```
{ 
   "questions" :[
       {
           "questionNum":1,
           "question": "Which list contains words that are NOT names of shoe types:"
           "choices":[ "A. Oxford, jelly, boat, clogs, stiletto, mary jane",
                       "B. Loafer, gladiator, wedge, mule, platform",
                       "C. Pump, moccasin, wingtip, sneaker, derby, monk",
                       "D. Chalupa, dogler, hamster, croonley, frankfurt",
                       " "
                     ],
                      "correctAnswer" : "D. Chalupa, dogler, hamster, croonley, frankfurt"
                 }
            ]
       }
```

Currently the program passes the values from the internal array to a div object and a radio list:

```
  function createQuestionElement(index) {
        var qElement = $('<div></div>', {
            id: 'question'
        });

        var header = $('<h2>Question ' + (index + 1) + ':</h2>');
        qElement.append(header);

        var question = $('<p>').append(questions[index].question);
        qElement.append(question);

        var radioButtons = createRadios(index);
        qElement.append(radioButtons);

        return qElement;
    }

  // Creates a list of the answer choices as radio inputs
    function createRadios(index) {
        var radioList = $('<ul>');
        var item;
        var input = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < questions[index].choices.length; i++) {
      item = $('<li>');
      input = '<input type="radio" name="answer" value=' + i + ' />';
      input += questions[index].choices[i];
      item.append(input);
      radioList.append(item);
    }
    return radioList;
  }
```

What would be the best way of getting the data from the JSON file?

Comment: You seem to know about the existence of [tag:ajax], have  you considered using it?

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you're asking. Are you looking for how to download the JSON file? Or how to handle it in JavaScript after it's downloaded? Or how to write code that works with your JSON data instead of the original data object? Or all of the above?

I would have made that a comment, but I want to mention something else, and since it involves code formatting, the only way to do it is in an answer - even though this won't answer your question. :-)

The indentation and formatting for both your original data object and the JSON data are all over the place. It makes it very hard to follow the actual structure of the data. If you use consistent formatting it becomes much easier to read. In fact, your `questions` object has an extra `}` in it so it won't even compile - but the inconsistent formatting obscures this.

One thing that will help you here is to use indentation only to show the nesting. Don't try to line things up in columns the way the "choices" array in your JSON data is laid out. Just use indentation for this.

Of course a JSON parser won't care about formatting; it ignores whitespace. But for people reading your code and data, it will make it easier for them.

For your original data, try:

```
var questions = [
    {
        question: "What is 2*5?",
        choices: [ 2, 5, 10, 15, 20 ],
        correctAnswer: 2
    }
];
```

And for the JSON data:

```
{
    "questions": [
        {
            "questionNum": 1,
            "question": "Which list contains words that are NOT names of shoe types:"
            "choices": [
                "A. Oxford, jelly, boat, clogs, stiletto, mary jane",
                "B. Loafer, gladiator, wedge, mule, platform",
                "C. Pump, moccasin, wingtip, sneaker, derby, monk",
                "D. Chalupa, dogler, hamster, croonley, frankfurt",
                " "
            ],
            "correctAnswer": "D. Chalupa, dogler, hamster, croonley, frankfurt"
        }
    ]
}
```

That said, your JSON data is almost identical in format to the original data object. The only differences I see are:

1. There is an additional `questionNum` property which you can ignore if you're not using it.
2. The `choices` and `correctAnswer` are strings, not numbers.
3. The JSON data has a `questions` array inside it, where the original data object has this array at the outermost level.

So, assuming you can take care of the number vs. string difference, and also assuming you've downloaded your JSON data into an object named `json`, you would probably just need to do:

```
var questions = json.questions;
```

and now all your code that processes the `questions` data should be just about the same. (Or you could just change `questions` to `json.questions` each place you use it.)

Now about your question on how to download the JSON data: Let's assume you have the JSON data file at `https://www.example.com/yourjson` or your server generates JSON data at that URL. Since you're using jQuery, you can download this data with:

```
var url = 'https://www.example.com/yourjson';
$.getJSON( url, function( json ) {
    // Here the JSON data is in your 'json' variable.
    // jQuery has already converted it to a JavaScript object for you.
    // So in your code here you can use:
    var questions = json.questions;
    // And now here you can use 'questions' like in your original code.
});
```

Note that the `json` data is only available *inside* the callback (where there are several comments above), or in any function you call *from* this callback (and pass it the questions data as an argument).

As another alternative with more options, you can use jQuery's `$.ajax()` instead of `$.getJSON()`. You have to specify a few more parameters when you do this, but it gives you the ability to do things like handle a server error as well as a successful download.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I will edit the format. As for the question itself, I suppose I'm asking how to write code the works with the JSON data instead of the original data.

Comment: Sounds good. I added a note about the difference between your original data array and the JSON data - I think you should be very close with just one minor change.

Comment: Apologies, I am a new to JSON, but could you go into a bit further detail on the "downloaded your JSON data into an object named json"?

Comment: Sure, I added a note on that too.

Comment: *"It's unclear what you're asking"* we have a close reason for that.

Comment: @KevinB Yes, I know, but I wanted to talk about the formatting of the JavaScript and JSON data, and there's no real way to do that other than posting an answer.

Comment: Many thanks for the replies. On the topic of the .getJSON, I'm using a JSON file called database.JSON, that's located within the same folder as the html and JS file on my computer. Would that work instead of an actual server file?

Comment: If you are loading your HTML page directly from your hard drive with a `file:` URL (or equivalently, a `C:\...` file path on Windows or similar on other OSes), then you probably won't be able to use `$.getJSON()`. Instead, to test this, run an actual web server on your machine and load your page with an `http:` URL like a normal web page. One easy way to do this is to install the latest version of [Python 3](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-362/), then open a cmd.exe or terminal window, `cd` to the directory with your files, and run `py -m http.server`.

Comment: Would the same have to be done, regarding the suggested steps with Python 3,  with .ajax() instead of .getJSON()?

Comment: Yes, `$.getJSON()` is simply a thin wrapper around `$.ajax()` with a few handy default values set for you. The restriction is actually on the underlying `XMLHttpRequest` that both of these are built upon.

Comment: While I was looking at this program only on the scope of being on my own computer, I failed to point out that this program will also be hosted on Microsoft Azure. Which has a sql server and an sql database. Will it still be possible to use .getJSON?

Comment: Yes, that is a very common thing to do, probably the most popular way of downloading data from any server to JavaScript running in a web page.